# Microsoft vs. GNU C/C++ standard library implementations

Tags: msvcrt, libc

Which one is better and cleaner from an implementation stand point so that one can recommend as a study guide? The way i see it, one can really learn a lot by just looking through those C library(with C++ things get ugly imho) implementations and toying with them, since they are rather simplistic in design and concept.
I am expecting non-biased answers from people who have looked through both implementations.

For people who didn't know, most of Microsoft's implementation of the C/C++ libraries is [available for debugging purposes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296413%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). You can find them in your Visual Studio installation folder under `VC\crt\src\`. Eg. for VS2008: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt\src`(assuming you installed a copy in `c:\Program Files\`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always wondered why C++ STL implementation used by Visual Studio is so hard to read, so I cannot recommend it for sure. I don't know about others implementations. e.g. [STLPort](http://www.stlport.org/)

Comment: +1 the STL implementation for VS might not be a good reading for learning purposes, at least for novices.